# Resize bitmap inside file without creating extra bitmaps/files?

Tags: android, bitmap, resize

I read a lot of topics where bitmap was resizes by decodeFile and createScaledBitmap. But I would like to change this file, without create extra bitmaps or files. It means, just when I open this file bitmap will be smaller/bigger.  Is it possibility?

Edit:
Specifically, I have jpeg files and I will zip this files, and before making zip I set size of images (in zip file).

Comment: do you just want to downsize it upon showing it, or actually resize the file on the file system?

Comment: Specifically, I have jpeg files and I will zip this files, and before making zip I set size of images. So I don't want to create additional files, and bitmap (cause then I had to store it in new file). I don't know if clearly explain :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not clearly understood, what you want to obtain, 
but here is a simple code to resize image file

```
    String your_file_path = "image.png";
    int set_scale_your_need  = 2;
    //getting your image size
    BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;

    BitmapFactory.decodeFile(your_file_path, o);
    o.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    o.inSampleSize = set_scale_your_need;

    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(your_file_path, o);
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(your_file_path, false);
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, fos);
    fos.flush();
```

Comment: Unfortunatelly, I don't see any change

Comment: sorry, i edit answer, just forget pass options second time). Also you need set scale your needed.

Comment: But unfortunatelly, it makes one problem: SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null). By the way, can I set something 120x120, not scale?

Comment: If you want set exact size to 120x120, first you need calculate scale for loading bitmap with size little above 120x120 in memory, and then use [Bitmap.createScaledBitmap](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#createScaledBitmap(android.graphics.Bitmap,%20int,%20int,%20boolean)) method

Comment: It's not enough info about your error. If it not related to this code, i think you need as new question.

Comment: According to question about set size not scale, why couldn't use only Bitmap.ScaledBitmap, is this scale such important, cause quality? Thank you for your patient

Comment: Sure, you are able not use scale first, it's just for avoiding OutOfMemoryException in cases of big bitmaps.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to have it open as a smaller version of it's self you can use `BitmapFactory.Options.inSampleSize` to reduce the load size.  If you want to actually resize the image and resave it to the file system, you will want to do that in an AsyncTask,

something like this:

```
public class ImageResizerTask extends AsyncTask<Integer, Void, Bitmap> {

    Bitmap mBitmap;
    String filePath;
    Context mContext;
    Activity mCallBack;
    //ProgressDialog pd;

    public ImageResizerTask(Context context, String path,
            Activity callBack) {

        mContext = context;
        filePath = path;
        mBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath);
        mCallBack = callBack;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {


    }

    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(Integer... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        resize(mBitmap);
        return mBitmap;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {
        //pd.dismiss();
        bitmap.recycle();
        mCallBack.onImageResized(filePath);

    }


    private void resize(Bitmap tmp) {

        final Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(500, 500,
                Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

        final Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);

        Log.v("TMPBMP",
                "temp bmp width:" + tmp.getWidth() + " height:"
                        + tmp.getHeight());

        if (tmp.getWidth() < tmp.getHeight()) {
            final int width = (int) (1f * tmp.getWidth() / tmp.getHeight() * 500);

            final int height = 500;
            final Bitmap scaled = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(tmp, width, height,
                    false);
            final int leftOffset = (bitmap.getWidth() - scaled.getWidth()) / 2;
            final int topOffset = 0;
            canvas.drawBitmap(scaled, leftOffset, topOffset, null);
        } else {
            final int width = 500;
            final int height = (int) (1f * tmp.getHeight() / tmp.getWidth() * 500);
            ;
            final Bitmap scaled = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(tmp, width, height,
                    false);
            final int leftOffset = 0;
            final int topOffset = (bitmap.getHeight() - scaled.getHeight()) / 2;
            canvas.drawBitmap(scaled, leftOffset, topOffset, null);
        }

        FileOutputStream outStream;

        try {
            outStream = new FileOutputStream(filePath);

            try {
                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, outStream);
                outStream.flush();
                outStream.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }


}
```